# Hash tables with strings in python

Tags: python, string, hashtable

This is the code of a working hash table, but this hash table doesn't work with string, and what I want to do is a contacts list, where as this hash table I can search, insert, delete and list the contacts, that are organised by (name,number,email).
what I'm lacking is:

- the delete function
- the table working with strings

```
MAX_HASH = 20

def hash(n):
    return n%MAX_HASH

def clearTable(n):
    table =[0 for i in range(n)]
    return table


def insert(elem, table):
    ii=hash(elem)
    if table[ii]==0:
       table[ii]=elem
    else:
       print("on the list")

def loadTable():
    table=clearTable(MAX_HASH)
    insert(245,table)
    insert(342,table)
    insert(194,table)
    insert(923,table)
    insert(556,table)
    return table

def findTable(elem,table):
    return table[hash(elem)]==elem


def menu():
    print(" ")
    print("1-search contact (name)")
    print("2-Insert new contact")
    print("3-List Contacts   ")
    print("0-Terminate  ")
    opcao=int(input("Option:"))
    return opcao

def repetir(hash_table):
    hash_table= loadTable()
    hash_table=clearTable(MAX_HASH)
    opcao=menu()
    while opcao!=0:
        if opcao==1:
            p = str(input('what do you want to search?:'))
            print(findTable(p,hash_table))           
        elif opcao==2:
            n = input('Insert name:')
            insert(n,hash_table)
        elif opcao==3:print(hash_table)      
        else :print("Option invalid")
        opcao=menu()
    print(" program's end")

hash_table= loadTable()
repetir(hash_table)
```

Comment: Is it working with strings or not? Please edit your question to fit quality standards. Explain why it's not working, what errors you get etc. We are not magicians. Give us something to solve your problem.

Comment: I don't get errors because i have no idea how to make it work with strings, the code is incomplete.

Comment: You know, hash-tables are called dictionaries in python?

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you are hoping we will do here. The only reason you would implement a hash table manually in Python, rather than using a dict, is for a class assignment; and we're certainly not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: You `hash()` function expects an integer argument `n` and tries to do arithmetic with it, `return n%MAX_HASH`. That's not going to work if `n` is string. You need to figure out a different way to hash strings that will work with your own custom implementation of a hash table — or use a Python dictionary which accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Take a look at the Wikipedia article on hashtables for ways to make a hashfunction for strings.

Comment: Mod-based hashes are ok, but you need to choose the table size carefully, eg, a prime, to minimize collisions. BTW, it's not good to use the name `hash` for your own function because it clashes with the built-in.

Comment: You might be able to the built-in [`id(object)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function which returns "an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime" to get a number to use to compute a hash value for strings (or any other type of object).